# Moving 10 DLC Numbers

Tags: twilio

With all the new regulations Im trying to move a number that I already own in twilio from a parent account to a sub account. Is this possible? If so, please indulge me because I have not found anything in their support or on youtube.

Tried Everything and nothing worked

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but you'll have to do it via an API as it is not available in the Console.

You'll need to make a POST request to the `IncomingPhoneNumber` resource of the phone number you want to move.

Here's an example:

```
curl -X POST https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC00000000000000000000000000000001/IncomingPhoneNumbers/PNXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.json  \
  --data-urlencode "AccountSid=AC00000000000000000000000000000002" \
  --data-urlencode "BundleSid=BUXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" \
  --data-urlencode "AddressSid=ADXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" \
  -u AC00000000000000000000000000000001:your_auth_token
```

In the snippet, you'll move the phone number `PNXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX` from the account `AC00000000000000000000000000000001` to the subaccount `AC00000000000000000000000000000002`.

You can also do this with the help of SDKs (Python, Java, Node.js, etc), you can check out more details in the [Twilio Docs to transfer phone numbers from a primary account to a subaccount](https://www.twilio.com/docs/iam/api/subaccounts#exchanging-numbers).